# Trackback spam protection. How to escape link blast

Tags: .htaccess, spam, spam-prevention, trackback, pingback

Lately some folks got into habit of creating trackback links pointing to my website from porn-related sources to de-index my site. They succeeded to a sertain extent, but I managed to spot them through GA and now I'm blocking their websites through .htaccess. The procedure is painful and I decided to ask you, good fellows, if you know how to block trackback links as they appear before it becomes a problem.
I know WP has some protection from backtrack spam, but I am not familliar with the mechanism.

Answer (score 0):

Spam is a well-known problem with Trackback and Pingback.

Possible measures against the spam:

1. Fetch the source and check if it really links to you
2. Pipe the request through a spam-analyzing service like Akismet
3. Pipe the source site content through a spam-analyzing service
4. Have a whitelist of people you know and trust, and block the rest. This isn't that nice for people you don't know and that send valid pingbacks.

More info: http://indiewebcamp.com/spam